# How to get country from Microsoft Graph API for Office 365?

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to fetch country of the logged in user using Graph API of Microsoft for Office 365.

I have downloaded code snippets for Microsoft Graph API in which I checked about the same. But it seems there is no any way to get it.

Is it possible to fetch country using Graph API?
If yes then what process should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

There is a country property on the User Object, which is not required to be populated. There is also 'preferredLanugage', 'postalCode', etc... check them all out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)

Here is an example of a graph api request to get the country code of the logged in user, using the 'me' endpoint:

```
https://graph.windows.net/me/country
```

You can try it using the [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fme%2Fcountry) (Note you will have to be signed in for this to work.)

More information on how to do stuff with a signed in user [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/signed-in-user-operations#GetMe).